# problems with copying objects with in java context

Tags: java

I just want to know the problems associated with copying objects within the Java context? any ideas?

Comment: Feel free to add more info on the question. It's not clear what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to know the difference between deep copy and shallow copy, and how to go about doing them, then [Wikipedia is your friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) here.

A quick way of performing a deep copy within Java is to serialize your source object tree then deserialize it into your target object tree. All references and contents are effectively cloned.

Use [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) to handle quick and easy shallow copying.